# Django get model by querystring

Tags: python, django, url, view

I want the user to be able to pass a querystring in url like `https://example.com/models?id=232`. But the query string is optional. so `https://example/models` should work too. Im trying this:

```
def myview(request, model):
        context = {
        'model': model,
        }
        if request.GET.get('id', None) != None and Model.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('id', None)).exists():
            id = request.GET.get('id', None)
            context['id'] = id
            return render(request, 'tests.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'tests.html', context)
```

S what is going on in the code above: i want to check if there is a query string (which is models id)  and if there exists this model. Bu tmy code does not work. If both of these requirement are not satisfied it should just load `tests.html` without `id` and without any errors. How can i do that? Also the `id` should just be number
Looking forward for your answers :D

Comment: did you have any errors? show your urls

Comment: i get error if i type string not number in url

Comment: show urls, add full error trace to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will getting an error `AttributeError: 'ModelName' object has no attribute 'exists'`, because `.exists()` function is available for `.filter(...)` method.

```
def myview(request, model):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    context = {'model': model, 'id': id}

    if id is not None and id.isdigit():
        if ModelName.objects.filter(pk=id).exists():
            context['id'] = id
    return render(request, 'tests.html', context)
```

Another way, you also can use with exception of `ModelName.DoesNotExist`;

```
# ...
from django.http import Http404

def myview(request, model):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    context = {'model': model, 'id': id}

    if id is not None and id.isdigit():
        try:
            obj = ModelName.objects.get(pk=id)
            context.update({'id': obj.id})
        except ModelName.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    return render(request, 'tests.html', context)
```

Comment: how can i get model without ".filter()" and not causing 404 error?